# Scrollspy list item flickering when scrolling up; using React

Tags: reactjs, scroll, intersection-observer

Trying to write some code in Javascript using the React library that will highlight the correct list item from a sidebar, based on which header from the body is in view. Each header corresponds to a list item. When scrolling down, the code runs fine; however, when scrolling up, the scrollspy flickers. That is, it will very briefly highlight a list item that is not the latest one visible (i.e., I want only the navbar item that corresponds to the header that is lowest-down on the page to be highlighted, and it will highlight a different navbar item).

I'm trying to use useEffect to sync up my code to the built-in Intersection Oberver API. Here's my useEffect code, happy to show anything else that helps:

```
    useEffect(() => {

      const options = {
        rootMargin: '0px',
        threshold: 0.5
      };

      const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
         
        const intersectingHeaders = entries.filter(entry => entry.isIntersecting);

          console.log('intersectingHeaders: ', intersectingHeaders);

          if (intersectingHeaders.length > 0) {
              let id = intersectingHeaders[intersectingHeaders.length - 1].target.getAttribute('id');
              setActiveHeader(id);
              console.log("id: ", id);
            }
        }, options)

      const headings = document.querySelectorAll('h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');
      headings.forEach((heading) => {
          observer.observe(heading);
      });
  })
```

I wrote this code expecting for only the lowest-down-on-the-page navbar item to be highlighted, but instead, a different item is briefly highlighted. However, that problematic behavior only crops up when scrolling upwards, not downwards.